# How to unmarshal a xml to format like <xxx /> instead of <xxx></xxx>

Tags: xml, go

The package encoding/xml provides a convenient way to parse or generate .xml files. However, the file generated are in format

```
<xxx attr1="aaa" attr2="bbb"></xxx>
```

even if there is no content in the element. Some server do not accept this kind of format.

So how to get the .xml file looks like

```
<xxx attr1="aaa" attr2="bbb" />
```

Comment: Not possible currently AFAICT. You might be able to do this in [Go 1.13, or 1.14](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21399)? For now you can use this [workaround](https://play.golang.org/p/W5cQkqS0h_), taken from this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/guG6iOCRu08)